# How to test _.defer() using Jasmine, AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, underscore.js

I already asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905088/scope-exists-on-browser-debugger-but-does-not-exist-in-terminal/27905400#27905400) where the main point was scope doesn't exists in terminal but it exists in Chrome debugging tool. Despite the answers it didn't get fixed.

The question is what is the right syntax to test the bellow directive, especially the line `expect(scope.measurementScroll).toBe(true);`. While digging through web i couldn't find any similar question most questions are related to `$q.defer()` where in my case there is underscore method `_.defer()`

Controller

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .controller('MeasurementsTimelineCtrl', ['$scope', '$state', 'Measurements', function($scope, $state, Measurements) {
    $scope.measurements = null;
    var userId = $scope.currentUser ? $scope.currentUser.id : null;
    if (userId) {
      var listOfMeasurements = Measurements.userIndex(userId);
      listOfMeasurements.then(function(data){
        $scope.measurements = data;
        $scope.$broadcast('measurements-updated', $scope.measurements);
      });
    }
  }]);
```

Directive:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('dashboardMeasurementTimeline', ['$window', function($window) {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: 'myView.html',
      controller: 'MeasurementsTimelineCtrl',
      link: function(scope, element){
        scope.$on('measurements-updated', function(measurements) {
          _.defer(function(){
            if(measurements) {
              scope.measurementScroll = true;
            }
          });
        });
      }
    };
  }]);
```

Test

```
'use strict';
describe('Directive: dashboardMeasurementTimeline', function () {

  var $rootScope, $compile, element, scope;

  beforeEach(function() {
    module('myApp');

    inject(function($injector) {
      $rootScope = $injector.get('$rootScope');
      $compile = $injector.get('$compile');
    });

    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    element = angular.element('<dashboard-measurement-timeline></dashboard-measurement-timeline>');
    element = $compile(element)(scope);

    scope.currentUser = {id : 'someId'};
    scope.$digest();
    scope.measurements = [{id: 'someId', time_of_test: 'Tue, 30 Dec 2014 14:00:00 -0000'},
      {id: 'someId', time_of_test: 'Thu, 20 Nov 2014 03:00:00 -0000'},];
    scope.$broadcast('measurements-updated', scope.measurements);
    scope.$apply();
  });

  it('should assign true value to measurementScroll', function () {
    expect(scope.measurementScroll).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Comment: the plugin that I use is `karma-jasmine: 0.1.5` while googling found that it's equivalent to Jasmine 2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by injecting a mock underscore library, with a `defer` function defined in the test. A way to do this is to define your own factory, `_`, which can then be mocked easily:

```
app.factory('_', function($window) {
  return $window._;
});
```

Then in the directive, you have to use it by injecting it:

```
app.directive('dashboardMeasurementTimeline', ['_', function(_) {
```

In the test, you can then mock it:

```
var deferCallback;
beforeEach(module(function($provide) {
  deferCallback = null;
  $provide.value('_', {
    defer: function(callback) {
      deferCallback = callback;
    }
  });
}));
```

This means that instead of the real one, the directive will use the mock `_`, which saves the callback passed to `defer` as `deferCallback` so you can invoke it when needed:

```
scope.$broadcast('measurements-updated', scope.measurements);
deferCallback();
```

This makes the test synchronous, which is usually a better idea than using `done()`, as it keeps test as fast as possible.

You can see the above working at http://plnkr.co/edit/r7P25jKzEFgE5j10bZgE?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much dear @Michal Charezma, your solution is the great and solves the problem

Comment: I have now one small issue, which is after mocking the `_` and importing it in directive, it raises an error when using other methods of `_` for example I am using:

`angular.element(scrollContainer).bind('scroll', _.throttle(scope.disableButtons, 500));
`
seems that the method `throttle()` doesn't  exist

Comment: @Max You should be able to add `throttle` to the object passed to `$provide.value`

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have lodash as a service to be injected you can just spy over the `defer` method, and if you care about the execution of the function passed then you can just set a `callFake` and call the argument function passed to the real `defer`:

```
spyOn(_, 'defer').and.callFake(f => f());
```

More deeper let's say you have the following call:

```
function toTest() {
 _.defer(() => service.callAFunction());
}
```

then in your test you can say:

```
it('should call service.callAFunction', () => {
   spyOn(service, 'callAFunction');
   spyOn(_, 'defer').and.callFake(f => f());
   toTest();
   expect(_.defer).toHaveBeenCalled();
   expect(service.callAFunction).toHaveBeenCalled();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Michal Charezma, gave a great solution for the problem that is actually a solution, but as it turned out it has some other restrictions for the rest of `_` functions. 
For example:

```
angular.element(scrollContainer).bind('scroll', _.throttle(scope.disableButtons, 500));
```

raises an error that the `throttle` is undefined.

Following @Michal's logic, found another solution that lets functions like `_.throttle()` to work properly. So, instead of importing `_` and using:

```
app.factory('_', function($window) {
  return $window._;
});
```

One can mock the `defer` function only, from the spec like:

```
var deferCallback = $window._.defer.mostRecentCall.args[0];
deferCallback()
```

Comment: I don't think this method actually makes a mock object. I suspect it might even cause the callbacks to defer to be executed twice, once when forced, and the other after the timeout inituated by the call to defer.

Comment: Ohhh, that's really interesting point have to check spec again. Thank you. )